# C# print goes infinitely while printing database value on multiple pages

Tags: c#, printing, oledb

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int kx = 25;
    int ky = 50;
    con.Close();
    con.Open();
    String sql = "SELECT * from cash_bill";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    while (dr1.Read()) 
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(dr1[7].ToString(), printFont, Brushes.Black, kx + 75, ky + 5);


        if (itemperpage < 29) 
        {
            itemperpage += 1; 
            e.HasMorePages = false; 
            ky = ky + 50;
        }

        else 
        {
            itemperpage = 0; 
            e.HasMorePages = true; 
             return;

        }

    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What happens when this code is recalled to print the second page? You re-execute the query and restart from the first record.

Comment: How many rows you have in cash_bill table?

Comment: cash_bill table has approx 9000 rows, I want to print 20 rows on each page

Answer (score 1):

1. Try **using** statement instead of open and close the connection
   every time.
2. Dont try to get all of the cash_bill rows in a single
   query. Try Top() keyword to limit the results.
3. Refine the query
   by adding an ID > X condition in your query.
4. Generate the query
   and make the call inside of the while loop. And update the X
   parameter by the greatest id value in the query result.

Example Query:

string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP({0})  from cash_bill where id > {1}", maxRowPerPage, maxRowId);

Update maxRowId at the end of every loop. (PS: I assumed that the values are ordered by Id)

This approach will reduce the time and code complexity of the code and increase the efficiency of the use of the sql connection.

Also, you may think to use multiple threads. Since you will collect the data of a single page by a single query by this improvement, you can manipulate and print data simultaneously.

Hope this helps.